# How can use garamond font in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, mathdesign, garamond, garamondx

I have seen several questions on how to enable the garamond font via downloading the garamondx or the mathdesign packages from ctan and copying the files to MikTeX directories in your own PC, but is there a way I can use the font in a Overleaf document?

(ps: I have already tried to add \usepackage{garamondx} to my preamble, but that runs in the same errors discussed in other questions)

Comment: You can upload the fonts to your project in Overleaf, if I remember correctly.

Comment: You mean, ulpoading the font's .sty file should do the trick, right?

Comment: @cfr, I just tried that and it is working just fine! Thanks.

Comment: I think, what cfr meant is that you can upload a .ttf or .otf file to your Overleaf directory and then use it with XeLaTeX and the `fontspec` package. You can also upload other fonts for use with (PDF)(La)TeX, but then you'd have to make sure to upload all necessary files (not only the .sty file, which does *not* include the font itself).

Answer (score 2):

EB Garamond is available in Overleaf.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Font test with EB Garamond. $x+y=0$.

\end{document}
```

So is Cormorant Garamond:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}

\begin{document}

Font test with Cormorant Garamond. $x+y=0$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: EB Garamond is more suitable as body text typeface than Cormorant which is a display typeface, as mentioned in the [illustrated presentation and description of the family](https://www.behance.net/gallery/28579883/Cormorant-an-open-source-display-font-family).

Answer (score 2):

In Overleaf, you can create the file `latexmkrc` with the contents:

```
$lualatex = 'TEXINPUTS=./optex//:$TEXINPUTS luatex -fmt=optex %O %S';
```

and set TeX engine `LuaLaTeX` in the Overleaf menu. These two steps makes ready to use OpTeX instead LaTeX. Then you can create a document:

```
\fontfam[Garamond]
The text of your document.
\bye
```

This creates a document with the EB Garamond and Garamond-Math fonts in Overleaf.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comments of `luisgmes96`, simply upload `garamondx.sty` cannot generate the pdf with the right font.

For now, I cannot find a solution to use `garamondx` package in **Overleaf**. So I just compile my doc in local. One can easily install the package by using `getnonfreefonts`.

For collaboration purpose, you may use Overleaf with the normal font instead, and then compile the doc in local for production.

At least, you can use some variants of garamond:

- ebgaramond
- CormorantGaramond
- garamondlibre