# How to get CTAN fonts in Overleaf

Tags: pdftex, overleaf, garamond

I want to write a document with Garamond typesetting (including math mode), particularly I found [this](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/). Reading some questions in this site, I think the approach I need is the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510581/how-can-use-garamond-font-in-overleaf), nevertheless I haven't been able to find what exactly I have to do for using this font in Overleaf.

I tried the only package related to Garamond font that seems to work in "stock" Overleaf, but the math mode doesn't use Garamond style (i.e. `\usepackage{garamondlibre}`), neither the text typesetting seems to be *exactly* (maybe I'm wrong) the same as "original" Garamond.

Thanks!

PD: I'm using pdfLaTex as compiler, even though I don't exactly know the different between this and LaTex compiler, post it just for information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to select LuaLaTeX and TeX Live 2020, and use just about any package in TeX Live. Failing that, you could create a directory named `fonts/` in your project folder, put any free fonts you want in that, and load them with `Path = ./fonts/` in `fontspec`.

This test file worked fine for me in Overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[ebgaramond]{fontsetup}

\title{Garamond Test.}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

And the following gives only a handful of warnings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{garamondlibre}
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\title{Garamond Test.}
\date{February 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```